# How to run a shortcut (.lnk) on startup - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, file-shortcut

I want to run a `.lnk` file on startup on Windows 10.

Methods that DON'T work:

- Using task scheduler - will only run the linked file (and that didn't work)
- Copying file to the run "shell:startup" location
- Copying file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: You want to run a certain executable or actually want to run a *.lnk* file?

Comment: I'm running a bat file. The .ink allows me to run this minimized.

Comment: No, that won't work. I actually don't know why but I have experience with it not running. A batch file itself isn't a program--it's just a cmd script. Best way to get it run minimized and run on startup is to convert into an executable file using [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) and making it an invisible application.